# What model to use to predict behavior of a group based on past behavior of group members

Tags: probability, prediction

What model to use to predict behavior of a group based on past behavior of group members.

I am using an analogy of sports team. 
Say we have data for individual players of sports. 
The data is the results of games between 2 teams and the members of each team. 
From this we can see how many times players have played together and the results each time. 
Win or Lose.

Today we know the roster of 2 teams playing. 
Is there a model to use that will take into account the past performance of each
player when they have played with the other players on the field today and use it to predict the winner of the game?

Comment: Sounds like Bayesian Statistics to me.  But I could be wrong.